# Problem in compilation of C++ code to WASM using emcc

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, dlib, webassembly

I am trying to compile the C++ code to WASM but facing problems in it. My C++ code included dlib and OpenCV libraries.  I have successfully compiled OpenCV and dlib for C++ environment. Also, I have installed emscripten in my system.

The directory structure is

C Drive

|..

|-- dlib

|-- emsdk

|-- opencv

|-- cpp_project

now when I am inside the cpp_project dir in command prompt (open in admin mode) I am executing the following command.

**emcc -msse3 -msimd128 -std=c++11 -O3 -I ../dlib ../opencv/build/include/opencv2/core.hpp ../dlib/dlib/all/source.cpp -lstdc++ -lpthread -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=4 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=1024MB -s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall', 'cwrap']" -s WASM=1 -o main.js**

I am getting the following error:

../opencv/build/include/opencv2/core.hpp:52:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/core/cvdef.h' file not found

#include "opencv2/core/cvdef.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

Please help me.

Comment: Why don't you use a modern open source C++ compiler such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) ? Whatever compiler you use, read its documentation and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). If you are learning C++ consider using a good Linux distribution like [Debian](http://debian.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change `-I ../dlib ../opencv/build/include/opencv2/core.hpp` to
`-I ../dlib -I ../opencv/build/include`

Comment: sir, can you please help me in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032793/unable-to-compile-c-code-having-opencv-usage-to-wasm